# How to match multiple linq expressions with logic?

Tags: c#, linq

I have multiple expressions in a List.

```
var expressions = new List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>() { .... };
```

I want to create an extension method to match them AND or OR logic.

```
public static class ExpressionExtension{

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And(this IList<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> exp){
        // for all items with AND
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or(this IList<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> exp){
        // for all items with OR
    }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at predicate builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion, I would reconsider how you name your extensions. They seem to correspond to the existing LINQ `All()` and `Any()` methods. You could add `And()` and `Or()` for single predicates, it would make a lot more sense.

Using [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> All<T>(this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> source) =>
        source.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.True<T>(),
            (acc, predicate) => acc.And(predicate) // And() provided by PredicateBuilder
        );

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Any<T>(this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> source) =>
        source.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.False<T>(),
            (acc, predicate) => acc.Or(predicate) // Or() provided by PredicateBuilder
        );
}
```

Comment: But this throws exception in entity framework. System.NotSupportedException: 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'